# How can I check memory usage in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is that possible to check memory usage in Elixir? (maybe calling Erlang)

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Check total memory usage - let's say **1G of 8G**
2. Read a **4G file**
3. Check total memory usage - let's say **5G of 8G**

Comment: You mean like `:erlang.memory()`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`:erlang.memory(:total)`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang#memory-0) was what I was looking for. Thank you [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) for pointing this out in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677595/how-can-i-check-memory-usage-in-elixir/42677887#comment72479694_42677595).