# How could I know amount of available memory on the server on elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I use 3rd party scripts from my elixir app. How could I know how much memory is available on my working app? I don't need the memory available by the erlang VM, but the whole computer memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677595/how-can-i-check-memory-usage-in-elixir

Comment: This is a duplication :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check memory usage in Elixir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677595/how-can-i-check-memory-usage-in-elixir)

Comment: @asiniy That's for the memory used by Elixir/Erlang, not the available memory on the system.

Comment: @Dogbert so my solution works better?

Comment: @asiniy yes, looks good to me. There's also `free -m` on Linux but it's harder to parse.

Answer (score 3):

A platform-agnostic way:

```
:memsup.start_link
:memsup.get_system_memory_data

[
  system_total_memory: 16754499584,
  free_swap: 4194299904,
  total_swap: 4194299904,
  cached_memory: 931536896, 
  buffered_memory: 113426432,
  free_memory: 13018746880,
  total_memory: 16754499584
]
```

So to get the total memory in MB:

```
mbyte = :math.pow(1024, 2) |> Kernel.trunc

:memsup.get_system_memory_data
|> Keyword.get(:system_total_memory)
|> Kernel.div(mbyte)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious (but a little bit cumbersome) way that I found is to call `vmstat` from command line and parse it results:

```
System.cmd("vmstat", ["-s", "-SM"]) 
  |> elem(0) 
  |> String.trim() 
  |> String.split() 
  |> List.first() 
  |> String.to_integer()
  |> Kernel.*(1_000_000) # convert megabytes to bytes
```

`vmstat` is the command which works on ubuntu and returns output like that:

```
         3986 M total memory
         3736 M used memory
         3048 M active memory
          525 M inactive memory
          249 M free memory
          117 M buffer memory
          930 M swap cache
            0 M total swap
            0 M used swap
            0 M free swap
      1431707 non-nice user cpu ticks
        56301 nice user cpu ticks
       232979 system cpu ticks
      3267984 idle cpu ticks
        84908 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
        15766 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
      4179948 pages paged in
      6422812 pages paged out
            0 pages swapped in
            0 pages swapped out
     35819291 interrupts
    145676723 CPU context switches
   1490259647 boot time
        67936 forks
```

Works on ubuntu, should work on every linux